# Beginner—use custom *.phtml for each page

Tags: theme, template, design

I am quiet new to magento and I about to code a custom template for a client. I would like to use **one** custom global main template file. By this I mean a template file that includes the:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    …
</html>
```

stuff. Due to [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento#dokuwiki__top) article I started by creating a `app/design/frontent/<my_template>/layout/local.xml` what is working nicely. But I also would like to override the »main entry point« of the template, which means: Starting at the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

In other words what I would like to do is something like this (in `local.xml`):

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template><my_template>.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setIsHandle">
                <applied>1</applied>
            </action>
        </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

where `<my_template>.phtml` is located in `app/design/frontend/<my_template>/template/`. But is does not work and how can I get that working?

Thanks in ahead!

Answer (score 2):

There is a second dimension to your problem. In addition to what David mentioned a lot of pages do not use the template set in the default node.

To see which pages this applies to you would need to go through the layout xml files here `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` (as well as any other merged layout xml instructions)

For example in `catalog.xml` you'll find

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

which you would need to set to your template with

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/mainfile.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

in your `local.xml`. Repeat for all uses of setTemplate on the root node in the other layout xml files.

Answer (score 1):

The section inside `<template>` should be placed inside the `template` folder. For example the following:

**Template**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/path/to/my_template.phtml
```

**XML**

```
<template>path/to/my_template.phtml</template>
```

Comment: that is somehow not working, but I don't got it totally, too. I have `app/design/frontend/<my_template>/default/template/page/<mainfile>.phtml`, so inside `<template>` should be: `page/<mainfile>.phtml`??

Comment: yes it should be fine, try putting it under base rather than `<my_template>` you may have an issue with your custom templte setup. Either that or is the layout file actually read? What happens if you put an error in the xml file i.e. remove a <

Comment: Invalidating the xml causes a waring shown in `var/log/system.log`, the (meanwhile new) `<remove>` statements do not work anymore. `<mainfile>.phtml` contains: `<?php die(); ?>` but it does not die.